# Out of Memory due to multiple consumers ActiveMQ

Tags: out-of-memory, activemq-classic, listener, consumer, multiple-constructors

I am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer as below :

```
private static final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MessageConsumer.class); 
    public static final DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = context.getBean(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
```

For a given queue that my listener listens to , the first time my program runs it starts the listener .... and this creates a Consumer for the queue that I can see in the Active MQ Console.

The problem I have is every time I checkin some new code, there is another new Consumer created for the queue and the old one is still hanging on creating some Out of Memory issue.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I make sure there is only 1 consumer and the old consumer is killed with every new code checkin? Hope I explained the issue clearly.

Comment: Please add full source code, logs and ActiveMQ version that you are having trouble with. Tip: The SpringJMSTemplate is really complicated to tune. The standard JMS API supports a callback listener pattern for subscribing and generally yields better success.

Comment: Hi Matt , I created a new post withh full code ... Can you please please look at this . Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148659/how-to-create-only-one-listener-for-a-queue-in-activemq-not-one-consumer-but